# Do I need to have seperate Facebook App ID for my same app in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-sdk-4.x

[For Facebook rejection detail Image refer this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7xLO.png)
My facebook app review got rejected recently for some reasons not related to this question. But in the reasons provided by review team there is this line

> If any of your platforms, (iOS, Android, other) don't use Facebook Login, please remove that platform from Settings. Please also ensure that you have a different App ID for the second platform.

So Do i need separate Apps in facebook developer console for my same app in two different platforms?

Comment: Yes. You need different app id's for different platforms. At the time of creating app id's you need to select(Mention) platforms for iOS, android.

Comment: But why are they allowing us to add details(like ios bundle identifier and android package name and activity name) of ios and android apps in the same facebook app console page via add platform button under single App ID. Furthermore even they allow us to attach ios app zip file and android apk file when sending for facebook review process under single App ID.
If you are sure, can you please add your source.

Comment: @PanneerdasP  did you submited simulator build of your app. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit

Please check here. In Step 4. 
If you already have submitted one then just tell them how to find the facebook button in your app.

Comment: @Ravi Prakash Thanks for responding. I failed to have facebook branding in the login button. But that's not what i am asking about. What i am asking is highlighted with red rectangle in the attached image("If any of your platforms, (iOS, Android, other) don't use Facebook Login, please remove that platform from Settings. Please also ensure that you have a different App ID for the second platform."). Why they want me to make sure that i have different App ID for second platform, If i can have app in two different platform under same App ID?

Comment: @PanneerdasP Sorry for the late reply, I think you have to ask them what they actually mean by the second app and App Id. I can't find any logical explanation for that.

Comment: @RaviPrakash Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need a different app, one app can be used by multiple platforms (Web, iOS, Android). 
Make sure you have removed the extra platform check the screenshot.
Following are the steps to remove the extra platform.

> Click MyApp -> Settings -> Basic -> Scroll Down

You will see similar to the attached screenshot. Click on the cross for the platform you are not using and save. Try submitting the app again. 
[image]

Comment: can you please see the image i have attached in my question and comment on it?